# Why i can’t connect to Gitlab on a container via SSH?

Tags: ssh, gitlab, containers

I have installed a local Gitlab in Portainer CE on Asustor.

I used putty to try to connect via SSH with the right port to Gitlab but it’s respond with “no supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey)”.

I try to create a new SSH key, and i put it on gitlab without success. On the Asustor the service of SSH is active in fact when i try to connect via SSH to the Asustor, it’s responde correctly. I used port 22 for SSH of Asustor and port 49165 for SSH of Gitlab. Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you have a `GIT_SSH` environment variable which would not use ssh.exe from Windows (`C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`) or from Git (`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`)

In general, there is no need for [PuttyGen](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html) to manage SSH connections on Windows.

If your GitLab runs in a Docker container on your NAS, you might need to map its internal SSH port to the host (Asustor) port 22, as described in [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/unable-to-connect-to-gitlab-docker-container-via-ssh/51915/5).